# Visual Studio 2015 Toolbox for Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I'm new in C++, I'm trying to create Windows Form Application, but toolbox doesn't works, so what I'm doing wrong.

1. "CLR Empty Project".
2. Windows Form (under UI).
3. Inside the CPP file:

> ```
> #include "MyForm.h"
> using namespace System;
> using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
> ```

```
    [STAThread]
    void main(array<String^>^ args) 
    {
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MYPROG::MyForm form;
        Application::Run(%form);
    }
```

4. In the Solution Explorer properties entry Point to "main"
5. SubSystem to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM/WINDOWS)"
6. Build MYPROG
7. Open MyForm.h
8. Open toolbox, right click and press "Show All", to drug button on MyForm

[But the tools does not works, looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeWJD.jpg)

Can you help me figure out with this problem

Comment: but please, don't target this c++. This is c++/CLI?

Comment: @qPCR4vir ok got it

Comment: @FirstStep thanks for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your project is `RUNNING`. So `STOP` the project then your toolbar items will become "enabled".

If my guess was wrong. Then Right-Click on a toolbox item and `Reset Toolbox`. Then they will get "enabled".

**Note** that you may lose any custom controls you added.

Comment: Warning: Any time you have to use the word "probably", you have a guess and not an answer. You might be right. Time will tell.

Comment: I have an answer for "a" reason @user4581301. But "_probably_" is for another reason.

Comment: Glad we were able to help :). @TimS